# random selecting value for second time in javascript fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have implemented two div classes **box** and box2, box2 can be dragged to any of **three** div classes box. class box contains **randomly** selected values from array **items** and class box2 contains its **correponding imagedisplayed** , so that it can be dragged to any of class box.

I have done the following

I have stored the corresponding images in **tempimages** array and tried to check if tempimages==0 in drop() function so that once values are over the counter takes value from array items and fill the class box.

Im not able to do the above mentioned looping

How to refill the box with values **once drop clears values in all three boxes**.

How do i correct it?

```js
var items = [  
      { label: '1:40', url: '1.png'  },
      { label: '2:20', url: '2.png'  },
      { label: '3:50', url: '3.png'  },
      { label: '4:45', url: '4.png'  },
      { label: '5:35', url: '5.png'  },
      { label: '6:10', url: '6.png'  },
      { label: '7:15', url: '7.png'  },
      { label: '8:10', url: '8.png'  },
      { label: '9:30', url: '9.png'  },
     { label: '10:40', url:'10.png' },
      { label: '11:20', url:'11.png' }
   ]

var tempimages = [];
var array2=[];
array2 = items.slice(); 


var len=array2.length;
console.log(len);
var item;



function rvalue() {
 
ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');


console.log(items);
console.log(array2);  

console.log(ptags);
console.log(ptags)


for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) 
     {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length),
      
      item = array2[randomIndex];
      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
      tempimages.push({data:item, index: randomIndex});
   
   ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
    }
 var tlen=tempimages.length;
    console.log(tempimages[0])
   console.log(tempimages);
 console.log(tlen);


}
 

function displayAllImages() 
{
  if (tempimages.length == 0) 
  {
 rvalue();
 //return;
 
  }
 item = tempimages.shift(); 
    image = document.getElementById('slide');
    image.src = item.data.url;
    image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
 
 
   
};

$(function() {
  
  rvalue();
  displayAllImages(); 
  
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(ev.srcElement);

 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 var el = document.getElementById(data);
 //alert(data);
 //alert(el);
 
 var x=document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
 var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;

// alert("x=>" + x + " y=>" + y);
  
 if(x==y)
  {
  el.parentNode.removeChild; 

  
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; 

  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  
  item=this.item;
  var arrayvalue=item.dataindex;
  array2.splice(arrayvalue,1);
  
 
  console.log(array2); 
  displayAllImages();
  
  console.log(tempimages.length);
  alert("sucessfull");
  if (tempimages.length == 0) 
  {
   alert("NO more images");
 rvalue();
 
  }
  
  }
  else{
  alert("WRONG PLACE");
  }

}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 35px;
 height:35px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid #333;
 border-color: #e6e600;
 margin:-2px;
 border-radius: 10%;
    background-color:   #bfff80;
 vertical-align: middle;

}
.box2 {
            float: left;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
   margin-top:3%;
   padding-top:2%;
   border:1px solid #000066;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
         
</div>
    
<div class="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
 <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:30px; height:30px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It can't possibly be *"to refill the box with values"*, right? What is the end goal of your application?

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu  once drop clears all the three values from 3 boxes at the top,  i want to again fill the boxes with random values from copies array array2,  im deleting the selected 3 values each time on drop, i want ro fill 3 values from the values remaining in array2 to these 3 div boxes

Comment: how to repeat rvalue() again

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve, without any reference to code? What should the user be able to do with your application? And what result should they expect from it? Do you want to reorder some data? Do you want to generate some result? Display something? Render a visual game? What is the end result? I'm asking because neither your explanation nor your code are making that clear and your question is unclear in current form. It will be closed if you don't ask something clear.

Comment: once drop is correct in box ie value and image(dropped) are correct the box dissappears, likewise 3 boxes and end of level1,  for level 2 next set of values should be displayed for the same process

Comment: yes im developing a matching game

Comment: im stuck in loading second set of values how do i correct it?

Comment: Ok, I get it: so you place some numbers randomly in the three divs and user has to drag and drop an image into the div that holds the number corresponding to the image displayed. Correct? And after this happens you want to reset the whole shebang and basically re-randomize? Is that it?

Comment: yes exactly how this can be corrected for the desired output